# get the age from date column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date

How can I extract the age of a person from a date column in a pandas dataframe (Current Date Format: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM)?

| ID | name | dateofbirth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Raj | 9/17/1966 01:37 |
| 1 | Joe | 11/13/1937 19:20 |
| 2 | mano | 1/5/1964 20:05 |
| 3 | Rishi | 11/13/1937 0:00 |

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
df['dateofbirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateofbirth'], format='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
df["Age"] = (now.date() - df['dateofbirth']).astype('<m8[Y]')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   ID   name         dateofbirth   Age
0   0    Raj 1966-09-17 01:37:00  51.0
1   1    Joe 1937-11-13 19:20:00  80.0
2   2   mano 1964-01-05 20:05:00  54.0
3   3  Rishi 1937-11-13 00:00:00  80.0
```

Comment: This works fine and if date is in format like '5/28/56 12:00 AM' then its throwing error :ValueError: time data '4/28/56 12:00 AM' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S'

Comment: You probably need to standardize the datetime

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract from now and convert to year:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.to_datetime(['9/17/1966 01:37', '11/13/1937 19:20',
                    '1/5/1964 20:05', '11/13/1937 0:00'])

age = (pd.to_datetime('now') - pd.to_datetime(s)).astype('<m8[Y]')

print(age)

Int64Index([51, 80, 54, 80], dtype='int64')
```